# Selenium tests without having to login on each test

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, factory-pattern

C# project with Selenium and NUnit, I use a Factory Design class so that tests are ran on one browser instance (Chrome). What I would like to do now is having all tests running without having to logon on each test. The scenario would be, run first test to logon and then all subsequent tests are done without requiring further logins. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reuse same `WebDriver` in all tests.

Login process will not be part of tests but part of `SetUpFixture` method.

Check here for example.